# Why aren’t walking snowmen on-topic?

Tags: discussion

I asked [a question](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/207190/touchscreen-controlled-dentist-office-snowman-collector-game) about a game with walking snowmen. It was [closed but then reopened](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/posts/207190/timeline) when Valorum found a video of the game that shows a “magic” meter.

Why are walking snowmen off-topic without other fantastical things? I don’t get it.

Comment: It was closed. You can see that in the [revision history](https://i.stack.imgur.com/plOZO.jpg) or in the [timeline](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/posts/207190/timeline). [Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/plOZO.jpg).

Answer (score 6):

In line with our policy regarding [talking animals](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5117/are-anthropomorphic-animals-by-themselves-enough-to-deem-a-work-fantasy), the mere existence of sentient/walking/talking snowmen (or any other thing that's normally non-sentient like [helicopters](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LSob3jGuPbY), [trains](https://youtu.be/ZOoHEDgWlZ0?t=640) or [diggers](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-P2-Nmk1uFQ)) in a property doesn't, in and of themselves, make that film/book/TV programme/comic a 'fantasy' **if the [central conceit](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Central_conceit) is that those "sentient *whatevers*" simply exist within that fictional universe without provoking explanation.**

That said, we would consider "sentient *whatevers*" to be part of a fantasy if:

- They had been **uplifted** in some way (either by [technology](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Mo8Qls0HnWo) or [magic](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Jtkq62PVfEI))
- Their speaking was somehow **fantastical [to the other characters](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gthEMHhS9zI)**.

---

With regard to your specific question, the mere presence of animated snowmen that you can push around with your finger **doesn't make it on-topic** (which is why it was closed). The fact that it was subsequently shown to contain some sort of power-up that allows you to perform magic **does make it on topic** (which is why it was reopened).

Comment: But unlike animals, there’s nothing animate in the first place about snowmen. Additionaly, artificially intelligent humanoid robots are sci-fi, but will likely exist in the future; snowmen cannot move by themselves, and that’s never gonna work. I think they’re fantasy.

Comment: @Stormblessed - There's nothing inherently animate about cutlery, but that doesn't mean that a film about them walking around is fantasy [per se](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=unKjeao254M)

Comment: @Stormblessed - Also, we've discussed [whether futuristic (but now current) science fiction gadgets and concepts are on-topic](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6535/if-a-show-was-speculative-in-1972-but-would-not-be-now-is-it-sf). The general thumb is yes, if they were considered sci-fi *at the time*. That means that writing fic that contains a hand-held mobile phone in 1953 would be firmly on-topic, but writing fic that contains a mobile phone today would be off-topic.